# Asp.net thread question

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have a number of threads that wait for a certain length of time and wake up to do some clean tasks over and over. I have not deployed this application to a production server yet but on my dev machine they seem to work as expected. For these threads to work the same on IIS7 do I need to look out for anything? Will IIS7 keep my threads alive indefinitely? are there implications to worry about?

Also I want to queue, lets say 50 objects that were created through various requests and process them all in one go. I'd like to maintain them inside a list and then process the list which means that the list object has to be kept alive indefinitely. I'd like to avoid serializing my objects into the DB in order to maintain this queue. What is the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Can anybody explain why this was downvoted? Additionally, take a look at `IRegisteredObject` and `HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject`. This will give you a notification if the application is unloaded. (I am not saying the question is a good or bad design, but in memory queuing can be helpful in many cases)

Comment: I'm tempted to vote down because you asked two very different, open-ended and vaugue questions.  Threading implications and IIS7?  I believe there are books on this.  Correct way of creating a queue? Thats an entire feature set of Azure.

Comment: @Dan Puzey, thanks for the advice, I had no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will IIS7 keep my threads alive
>   indefinitely?

No, if the application pool recycles (if there's a long inactivity or some memory threshold is hit) those threads will be stopped as the application will be unloaded from memory. If those objects are so much precise I wouldn't recommend you keeping them in memory but rather serialize them to some persistent storage so that they could be processed later in case of failure.

Comment: Can anything at all be done about this and does IIS7 recycle the pool often in your experience?

Comment: You could disable application pool recycling in IIS7 as it does by default under some circumstances.

Comment: You can, but it's generally not sensible to do so.  I'd definitely go with your persistent storage suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The design you describe is fine when you don't mind losing cached commands in the queue. Otherwise it would be better to go with a different design. ASP.NET isn't suited for this type of processing, because IIS can recycle the process. When that happens you lose your in-memory queue. IIS could also decide to unload the AppDomain because no new requests are coming in. In that case your threads will also stop running which means that pending operations will still not been cached, even when you use a persisted queue.

You'd probably be better of with some sort of transactional queue, such as MSMQ or a custom table in the database (or look at the open source [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com/)). Adding operations to the queue can be done by your web application and processing items can be done within a Windows service application that will not be recycled and can process the queue in a transactional way.

Since you're talking about multiple threads: when using a Windows service you can build it in such way that it can run multiple threads or make it single threaded and run several instances of the same thread. This is a very flexible design that I used successfully in the past to distribute CPU and disk intensive operations over multiple machines.